# cassandra creating and using index [pycassa]

Tags: python, indexing, cassandra, pycassa

I would like to create and use an index on "age" key of a standard column family.

I did the following using pycassa:

```
In [10]: sys.create_index('test01', 'word_map', 'age', 'IntegerType', index_type=0, index_name='index_age')
In [11]: age_expr = create_index_expression('age', 6, GT)
In [12]: clause = create_index_clause([age_expr], count=20)
In [13]: cf.get_indexed_slices(clause)

error: 'No indexed columns present in index clause with operator EQ'
```

According to this nice [page](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes), I need to set the value type. However:

```
In [16]:  cf_words.column_validators
Out[16]: {'black_white': 'BooleanType', 'url': 'UTF8Type', 'age': 'IntegerType', 'site': 'UTF8Type', 'len': 'IntegerType', 'content': 'UTF8Type', 'colourful': 'BooleanType', 'printer_friendly': 'BooleanType'}
```

so age has a data type set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the string 'GT', use `pycassa.index.GT`.  It's an enum that Thrift implements with integers.

You can find all of the documentation and an example usage here: http://pycassa.github.com/pycassa/api/pycassa/index.html

Comment: If I used pycassa.index.GT it says NameError: global name 'pycassa' is not defined Changing the code to 'GT' to GT gives me a different error: "No indexed columns present in index clause with operator EQ"

Comment: @rikAtee You need to do something like 'from pycassa.index import GT' and then you can just use GT directly.  The "no indexed columns present in index clause" is because you have to have at least one EQ expression in your clause that deals with an indexed column for secondary index queries with Cassandra.

Comment: I did: sys.alter_column('test01','word_map','age','IntegerType')
and:   sys.create_index('test01','word_map','age','IntegerType')

and I still get "InvalidRequestException(why='No indexed columns present in index clause with operator EQ')"

Comment: @rikAtee you have to have an EQ expression on at least one indexed column. You're only using a GT expression right now; even though that column is indexed, it's not enough.